# Asp.net + C#: Copy DataColumn from tableA to table B

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to copy DataColumn from tableA to table B:

As I think it should be like this:

> TableA in perdefined.
>
> DataColumn[] dataColum = new
>   DataColumn[TableA .Columns.Count];
>
> TableA .Columns.CopyTo(dataColum, 0);
>
> DataTable TableB = new DataTable();
>
> TableB .Columns.AddRange(dataColum);
>   //

=> but it raised an error at the line error, ID is belong to another table (in tableB)...

As I dont like another way:

> DataTable TableB = TableA.Copy();
>   TableB.Clear(); // => getting
>   structure of table A, not nice this
>   way

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [DataTable.Clone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.clone.aspx) method that copies only structure (i.e all columns & constraints) unlike Copy that copies data also.

In case you need to copy a particular column then you need to use code such as `TableB.Columns.Add(columnToAdd.ColumnName, columnToAdd.DataType)`

Comment: Hi VinayC,

Yes, using Clone method can copy the structure A to B.
Thanks!